# Php GET array0 on server

Tags: php, server, get, var-dump

On my localhost when I use php `<?php echo var_dump($_GET); ?>` I get this `array(1) { ["lng"]=> string(3) "eng" }`
But on server I get this `array(0) { }`.

Everything is exactly the same as on localhost.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["lng"])) { ?>
<li class="language"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="index.php?lng=eng"> English</a></li>
<?php }
else if($_GET["lng"] == "eng") { ?>
<li class="language"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="index.php?lng=srb"> Srpski</a></li>
<?php }
else if($_GET["lng"] == "srb") { ?>
<li class="language"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="index.php?lng=eng"> English</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: did you passed the get parameter on your server?

Comment: what is your url, is querystring is there in url

Comment: url is http://www.myserver.rs/?lng=eng

Comment: What happens if you paste the URL into the browser? Try it with other URL parameters (e.g., `?lng=eng&test=yes&whoami=Kosta`) to see if your `lng` parameter is being filtered out by your Apache config (or .htaccess file).

Comment: is `lse if($_GET["lng"] == "srb") {` a typo (missing e)

Comment: @MrGlass Thans i fix my problem.I open my `.httaccess` file and i remove `Options -indexes` .Now working but i have another problem when i go to mysite `www.mysite.com` i redirect to page `Indexed of` and i need to click MySite to load site...

Comment: If you add `DirectoryIndex name-of-your-file.ext` to your htaccess file it should load the page you want.

Comment: Still problem... my .httaccess file: 
# BEGIN WordPress
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MySite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /MySite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: Fixed just add FolderName/index.php